# CI - img function doesn't work

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is my first time using CI, when I was trying to use img(), it was not working. When I viewed page resource, I found that code which called image is showed like this  `<img src="http://::1/lat2/asset/images/ci_logo2.gif" alt=""/>`i I notice that host should not `::1` but `localhost`. Thats why the image is not showed. so, how to solve that?

here is the c_view.php I put on controllers folder:

```
<?php
class c_view extends CI_Controller{
    function img(){
        $data["judulapp"]="Menampilkan Gambar Dengan img()";
        $this->load->view("v_cview_img",$data);
    }
}
?>
```

And this is v_cview_img.php I put on views folder :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$judulapp;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2><?=$judulapp;?></h2>
    echo img("asset/images/ci_logo2.gif")
    <br />
    <?=img("asset/images/ci_logo2.gif");?>
    <hr />
    <?=img("http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/unsupprtd_brwsr/yahoo_logo_id_083109.gif");?>
    <hr />
    <pre>
    $myimage=array(
        "src"=>"asset/images/ci_logo2.gif"
        ,"alt"=>"Logo CodeIgniter - Api menyala!"
        ,'width' => '200'
        ,'height' => '200'
        ,'title' => 'Logo CodeIgniter'
        );
    echo img($myimage)
    </pre>
    <?
    $myimage=array(
        "src"=>"asset/images/ci_logo2.gif"
        ,"alt"=>"Logo CodeIgniter - Api menyala!"
        ,'width' => '200'
        ,'height' => '200'
        ,'title' => 'Logo CodeIgniter'
        );
    echo img($myimage);
    ?>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using `base_url()` instead of typing the entire url path.

Comment: @sa-7 what is gonna be like?

Comment: check niranjan-n-raju answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you waht to do this, you have to created custom `URL Helper`.

In application/helpers folder, create a file called `My_url_helper.php` and this code.

```
<?php
function theme_url($uri)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->base_url('app/themes/'.$CI->config->item('theme').'/'.$uri);
}

function img($uri, $tag=false)
{
    if($tag)
    {
        return '<img src="'.theme_url('assets/images/'.$uri).'" alt="'.$tag.'">';// path where your image is stored.
    }
    else
    {
        return theme_url('assets/images/'.$uri);
    }

}
```

In view,

```
<img id="logo" src="<?php echo img('logo.png'); ?>" alt="XYZ" />
                                    ^ name of the image you want to load.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is returning the IPv6 version of localhost (::1) rather than the IPv4 one (127.0.0.1) and is not fully configured to handle IPv6.

Often this is due to the setup of your `/etc/hosts` file. Try changing the first non-comment line of `/etc/hosts` to the following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: where can I change that ?

Answer (score 0):

In you code

```
$myimage=array(
    "src"=>"asset/images/ci_logo2.gif"
    ,"alt"=>"Logo CodeIgniter - Api menyala!"
    ,'width' => '200'
    ,'height' => '200'
    ,'title' => 'Logo CodeIgniter'
    );
echo img($myimage)
```

actually this will use in CakePHP. For Codeigniter use  just `<img>` tag

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>asset/images/ci_logo2.gif" alt="Logo CodeIgniter - Api menyala!" >
```

[`<img>` tag in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

---

In order to use `base_url()` in  `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; # keep empty
```